# Syncfusion dashboard layout initial render is invalid (vue.js and ASP.MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, dashboard, syncfusion

everyone!
I have a veird issue with the Syncfusion dashboard layout.
It is rendered weirdly.

I took the examples that they have on their site for **MVC5** and **Vue**, but they work the same way (similar).

So the issue is that the **layout** **is** rendered **overlapped** in both cases.

[image]
[image]

And after manually resizing the window, everything starts to be displayed properly.

[image]
[image]

Does anybody know what can be the reason behind this?